# Using For Loop to Check for duplicates - Error The error is: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: vb.net, nullreferenceexception

I have a problem that I and my limited experience cannot figure out.

I have a multi-display (form) program that is for a game show system which uses a (5) display system. As I am wrapping this project up, I have been doing some house keeping and handling some potential user errors up front.

In this instance:  There is a form called `GameSetup` which has drop down menus that are filled via a database selection of "Teams".  When a `Team` is selected, (10) labels are populated with registered team members. The user drags and drops a team member (ie. player) to a group of (6) labels, which will make up the active team for the game.

The problem:  I wanted to have a check when a name is added to the active team roster to make sure there are no duplicates. The cleanest way to do this, I thought, would be on the `.TextChanged` action of the active player label and use a `For` loop to check the other active team player names.

```
    Private Sub lblT1_P1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lblT1_P1.TextChanged

    cmdReady.BackColor = Color.Yellow

    For i = 1 To 6

        If i = 1 Then

            ' Do nothing

        ElseIf Me.Controls("lblT1_P" & i.ToString).Text = lblT1_P1.Text Then 'This is the line triggering the NullException

            MsgBox("This Player is already selected. Please choose another Player", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly)
            Me.Controls("lblT1_P" & i.ToString).Text = "DRAG PLAYER HERE" 'This is the other line triggering the NullException

        End If

    Next i

End Sub
```

`i = 1 Do Nothing` is so that it wont compare against itself (in this instance)

When I run the program (de-bug), before the form `GameSetup` loads, I am getting a Null Exception, which makes sense as it is looking at a form or an object in a form that is not yet initialized. Clearly, the `Me.Controls` is the problem, but I do not know how to handle using the integer (i) in the For Loop otherwise.

The label names are `lblT1_P1` - `lblT1_P6` (3 instance of each group (T1/T2/T3). I'm only dealing with `T1_P1` at the moment.

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use string.Format() to generate your control names, because it is more readable.

Instead of **Me.controls("lblName").Text** 
use **DirectCast(Me.FindControl("lblName"), Label).Text**

Comment: Thank you!  I haven't used FindControl before.  Is that a member of DirectCast or something I need to declare in the Class?

Comment: @ChrisLink Refer [DirectCast] (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7k6y2h6x.aspx) and [FindControl] (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/31hxzsdw(v=vs.110).aspx)